# Bash xmlstarlet + variable not work

Tags: bash, variables, xmlstarlet

I have a problem with my code..

That works fine :

```
xmlstarlet ed --inplace -u '//data[irc="Blablabla"]/usercount' -v $count myfile.xml
```

But that not :

```
variable="Blablabla"    
xmlstarlet ed --inplace -u '//data[irc="$variable"]/usercount' -v $count myfile.xml
```

usercount don't change value and I don't know why :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cheap, easy and wrong way is just to change your quoting type:

```
variable="Blablabla" 
xmlstarlet ed --inplace \
  -u "//data[irc=\"$variable\"]/usercount" \
  -v "$count" \
  myfile.xml
```

...that is to say, change the single quotes in `-u 'foo'` to double quotes, as in `-u "foo"`.

---

Best practice is to pass your shell variable in as an XPath variable, and then use it as such in your query:

```
variable="Blablabla" 
xmlstarlet ed --inplace \
  --var variable "'$variable'" \
  -u '//data[irc=$variable]/usercount' \
  -v "$count" \
  myfile.xml
```

This avoids mixing code and data -- a practice which is the root cause of almost all varieties of injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Work perfectly ! Thank you very much :D